# How to implement box constraints in QuadProg

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, quadprog

I was wondering if the R ‘Quadprog’ package has the ability to incorporate box constraints of the following form: -L*1 <= v <= L*1

Where 1 is a vector of 1’s and L is a constant. The variable to optimize is v. Basically all individual elements of v must be bounded between –lambda and lambda.

If not, are there other packages to get around this problem?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: The image is not necessary, it's just about the constraint -L*1 <= v <= L*1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Given the function:

```
solve.QP(Dmat=Dmat,dvec=dvec,Amat=Amat,bvec=bvec,meq=0)
```

`Amat` and `bvec` means `Amat * v >= bvec`.

So setting in this way:

```
Amat <- cbind(diag(length(v)), -diag(length(v))) 
bvec <- c(rep(-L, length(v)), rep(-L, length(v)))
```

means `v > -L` and `-v > -L` (that is the same than `v < L`) for every individual element of `v`.

Note `meq` means "number of equalities", and because in your case all are inequalities it must be put to `0`.

If you need to put equalities constrains, put it in the "left" side of `Amat` and `bvec` and the number of equalities in `meq`.